# In virtual machine manager, is there a way to add disk space to an existing disk?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I know that in [`virt-manager`](http://virt-manager.org/) you can add RAM and processors to the virtual machine, but is there a way to increase the available disk space larger through the GUI?

Edit: @slm was able to find the answer, using the command line is the only way on the program I'm using.

Edit again: @slm had the best answer, but he posted it as a comment. I was looking for a way to increase the disk size of my virtual machine using `virt-manager`, as there is no way to do it through the GUI of this program. All I could find online were tutorials on how to do it through different programs' GUIs, which was not applicable to `virt-manager`. Hopefully this clarifies what I was asking.

Comment: You can either add new disks, or edit the existing one. Then depending on whether your VM's disk management you can then expand the partition/volumes. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/266.how-to-increase-the-vhd-size-in-hyper-v-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: There are several methods discussed in this Q&A over on ServerFault that I asked a while ago: http://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space/324289#324289. They cover KVM specifically, but you can increase the space both online and offline.

Comment: This question has been covered a number of times, did you do any searching of the archives here or in serverfault or superuser?

Comment: @mdpc Yea I searched here, I just did another search and found nothing. No I didn't search through each stack exchange individually. None of the stackexchanges came up when I searched from google.

Comment: @DravSloan I found a number of tutorials for other virtual machine management software, but I guess the GUI to the one I use doesn't let me just amount of allotted space. I have to go in from the kernel.

Comment: That depends on the virtual machine software, on the disk configuration in the guest, on the filesystems…

Comment: What virtualization technology are you using? Which tool is VMM? A little more info would help us to know how to direct you better.

Comment: @sim Virtual Machine Manager(virt, I guess). I thought it was more common as this was highly recommended to me. Your answer was correct, doing it through the KVM is the best way, although I'm not supposed post a comment thanking you, and I can't select yours as the best answer because you left it as a comment. I edited the text saying that you had the best answer.

Comment: @jack - yeah I'm familiar with `virt-manager`, that's what I use every day, I've never heard it referred to as VMM. I think that was what through your question into the "close it" camp. I have several years of experience with that tool, and there is no way to increase the disk space of an existing disk. You can add more virtual disks, but you can't grow them. The command line is the only way you can do this. The command line is actually very straight-forward and easy to do.

Comment: @sim Yes. Its done.

Comment: @slm you may as well make that into an answer.

Comment: @slm yea I was just calling it what it said at the top of the GUI window, but I guess that's neither the name nor what people call it by. Why they named the window that is beyond me. Also, it seems that most of the features are not in the GUI either.

Comment: @JFA - yes the GUI is very much a work in progress. I recently moved from the CentOS 5 version to the CentOS 6 and the Fedora 19 and they're very different. A lot more features in Fedora 19's now. So it's slowly coming along. Remember that KVM is really a server product so it's not as slick as VirtualBox. I generally deal with it from the command line.